# Creating a counter

Tags: javascript, loops, time, while-loop

I'm creating a counter and I'm having a hard time making it.
The goal of the counter is that for ever second passed a number will increase by 170. 
As you can see below the number does not add up and is made on a new line, mostly because I dont know how to make it add up.  Some thing like this clock from [The Economist](http://www.economist.com/content/global_debt_clock)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Click the button see how much AirHelps market increases by every second.</p>

<button onclick="counterFunction()">See it now</button>

<p id="counter"></p>

<script>
function counterFunction() {
setTimeout(function () {
    var text = "";
    var i = 170;
    while (i < 3500) {
        text += "<br>The number is " + i;
        i+=170;
    }, 1000) }

document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on how I can make this and what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use inline JavaScript (JavaScript inside HTML element attributes), it is horrible for maintainability and readability.

You seem to have a misconception about how timeouts, intervals and while loops work, what you want is an interval.

Define a count variable outside of the event listener function, then on each iteration of the interval increment the count variable by one and multiply that number by 170.

I added a little bit in there to hide the button once it has been clicked, just to stop the user from restarting the counter.

```js
var clicker = document.getElementById('clicker');
var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
var count = 0;

clicker.onclick = function() {
  setInterval(function () {
    counter.textContent = "The number is " + ++count * 170;
  }, 1000);
  clicker.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button see how much AirHelps market increases by every second.</p>

<button id="clicker">See it now</button>

<p id="counter"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/mblenton/Le4vxzrn/2/

```
function counterFunction() {
    var text = ""; var i = 170;  var delay = 0;  var k = 1;
    while (i < 3500) {
        text = "The number is " + i;
        i += 170;
        delay = k * 1000;
        doSetTimeout(text, delay);
        k++; 
   }
 }

function doSetTimeout(text, delay) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById("counter").textContent = text;
 }, delay);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval), not [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)`. Note that if you click the button, it will reset your timer.

You also need to declare `var i` and `var text` outside the scope of the Interval, or they will also be reset each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the adder variable should be declared outside of the timeout function, because if not you are replacing the value. and you should use setInterval

```
var p =0;

function counterFunction(){
setInterval(function(){ p+=170;
console.log('value of p '+p);
 }, 3000);
}
```

if you dont want to roll your own here is a nice counter
http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Comment: `p` is going in increments of 170, not 1. This is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few things wrong with your code. Among other things:

1. your `i` variable was declared in the wrong place to be reused
2. your closing braces were in the wrong place for the callback function
3. you were using a `while` loop, which runs synchronously, whereas you really want to just use a `setInterval` call.

This should work:

```js
function counterFunction() {
  var i = 170;
  var text = "";
  var interval = setInterval(function () {
    text += "<br>The number is " + i;
    i+=170;
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = text;
    if (i >= 3500) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000); 

}
```

```html
<p>Click the button see how much AirHelps market increases by every second.</p>

<button onclick="counterFunction()">See it now</button>

<p id="counter"></p>
```